# When I Try to select rows where the trimmed value of a column is not null, it still returns rows with null values (Snowflake)

Tags: sql, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, trim

```
SELECT Client_id, first_name, mobile_number 
FROM client_table 
WHERE trim(mobile_number) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Remember, the **tags** attract the right audience to your question, so if you use irrelevant tags you get the wrong audience and the audience you want don't see that question.

Answer (score 1):

Trim does not make the value as NULL but instead an empty string

```js
create or replace table table2 (province varchar);
insert into table2 (province) values
    ('  '),
    (' ');
    
    select trim(province) from table2 where trim(province,' ') = '';
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/trim.html

Comment: This is true for most databases. Of the ones I know, only Oracle treats an empty string as null.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of mobile_number can be a null or blanks, I normally do something like this:
WHERE COALESCE(trim(mobile_number), '') <> ''